Do gravitational waves cause matter to radiate?
Gravitational waves distort the "fabric" of spacetime. In doing so, it seems they can cause particles to accelerate.
On the other hand, textbook electromagnetism predicts accelerated charges radiate, and hence lose energy.
Would gravitational waves, which cause oscillation detectable with interferometers, cause matter in the gravitational wave to radiate? If so, why isn’t the ocean glowing in RF? If they don't lead to radiation, what keeps them from it?

I admit that my previous version of the question is rather not rigorous and have clarified the question.

The question is still unclear and mixes elements (e.g. uncertainty principle) in an unclear way. Please, remove all the non-essential things. What is, in a sentence, your question? Whether or not a multipole (say a dipole) emits if a GW passes by?

Also, don't make your question look like a revision history, there's existing framework for that (click on the "edited X TIME ago" link or the clock icon under the post score).

I have fixed the problems. The question was and always have been the title, it is also now further explained in the last paragraph, which is and have always been there.

@robinwang I completely rewrote your question, trying to keep in mind what your goal was. Please check if the new version is okay with you.

Gravitational waves won’t accelerate the objects. It would constrain the wave functions in the coordinate basis, causing a shift in momentum. In a way the objects themselves accelerate to resist change in spacetime distortions.

The general idea is the same but I was trying to avoid some answers that would try to dismiss the question by stating that gravity doesn’t exactly accelerate things.

I have simply no idea, why this question got a -9. There are points where sanity simply stops and we must recognize the behavior of others as obviously out of anything rational. These 9 downers are belonging clearly to this group.

@peterh Keep in mind that downvotes do not disappear after a question is edited, and the version you see now might not be what was downvoted initially

Let us assume that our gravitational waves are described by a linearized Einstein equation, so that the metric is of the form
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}
$$
Where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the flat Minkowski metric and the components of $h_{\mu\nu}$ are "small" in the sense that terms of quadratic or higher order in them can be neglected. From gauge freedom arguments that I will not repeat now (The wikipedia article about linearized gravity explains it quite succintly), one can conclude that $g_{\mu\nu}$ must be of the form
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0&0\\
0&1+h_+&h_\times&0\\0&h_\times&1-h_+&0\\0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now we write Maxwell's equation in curved spacetime
$$
0=\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\det g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\left(\sqrt{-\det g}F^{\mu\nu}\right)
$$
But consider now the determinant of the metric tensor
$$
\det g = h_\times^2 - (1+h_+)(1-h_+) = h_\times^2 - 1 + h_+^2 \approx -1
$$
So that Maxwell's equation reduces to the case of flat space, meaning that the gravitational wave has no impact and therefore no radiation can occur. For nonlinear gravitational waves, there might be an effect, but I conjecture that the energies required for this are beyond the scope of modern physics.

This is pretty much the correct answer. For a wave to be described perturbatively it must also effectively have zero radiation. Easy as that!

By this argument Hawking radiation can not exist. What am I missing?

@FlatterMann the point is that in my argument, there is no radiation because the linear effects of gravity do not result in an acceleration of charges. Hawking radiation comes from considering the Schwarzschild metric, which solves the full nonlinear Einstein equation.

You don't mention a four-current, so is the assumption that you are solving $\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$? If so, I don't think you need to use perturbation theory here. I think for an arbitrary gravitational background, you should find $F_{\mu\nu}=0$, assuming appropriate asymptotic boundary conditions, since the gravitational field has no charge, and we're assuming no other charges or currents.

I understand that, but doesn't the piecewise linearization of the static Schwarzschild metric give us the same result because of the local symmetry? I am not trying to be provocative. I think my intuition is really stuck on this one. I will think a bit more about it.

@Andrew maybe writing "solve" was a poor choice of wording. The point is that linearized gravity does not change Maxwell's equation in a meaningful way, so that the wave cannot have a measurable effect which would result in radiation, hence no radiation occurs.

Gravitational waves passing through the Earth cause strains on the order of $h\approx10^{-20}$ - see here and here. This means that a gravitational wave changes the length of a meter stick by about one one hundred quintillionth of a meter.
Putting strain on spacetime could lead to (minute) changes in particles' momentum, but in reality such a change is so small that it's negligible. The only way we're able to detect G-waves is by setting up massive interferometers and carefully detecting the observation of the length of the laser beam changing by the invisible amount prescribed by the strain of the gravitational wave. There has never been any observation of gravitational waves meaningfully affecting any physical system except those specifically designed to react to gravitational waves, because a strain of $10^{-20}$ is so small that even at the quantum scale the strain it puts on particles is virtually negligible.
For a proton, the total strain would yield a maximum distance change near the Planck scale at $h=10^{-20}$ ($\Delta L\approx10^{-35}$), which is hardly going to affect the proton's wavefunction in a measurable way. With current (and probably even near-future technology) technology and physics theories, mapping the proton's wave function to that precision is not known to be possible.

Would this phenomenon happen if the earth was closer?

To the gravitational wave source? Sure, if you place a strong gravitational wave source near the earth, the gravitational wave could have sufficient power to cause matter to radiate. The strain would have to be large enough to cause meaningful movement of atoms. If the source is close enough to do that, it's also strong enough to make matter do other interesting things due to gamma radiation burst/massive mass outflow. In other words, if two black holes/neutron stars collide close enough to us to make matter radiate, matter will be doing much more than just radiating.

It depends on your exact setup but in theory you could arrange for gravitational waves to generate electromagnetic radiation, however in practice I don't think this scenario is very plausible to occur naturally.
First, a situation that would not produce electromagnetic radiation would be to have gravitational waves pass through through a freely falling classical charged particle, not near any other charges. Because of the equivalence principle, a freely falling observer is equivalent to an inertial observer. So (unless the wavelength of the gravitational waves was small compared to the size of the particle, which runs against being able to think of it as classical particle in the first place), the particle will follow a geodesic in the spacetime as the wave passes, so will not radiate.
To actually generate some interesting acceleration of the kind that can produce acceleration, we need to introduce more interesting matter, with an internal structure that fights against the stresses induced by the gravitational field. The basic idea of a lump of matter that is excited outside of its ground state by a passing gravitational field is the core concept behind a resonant bar detector. A passing gravitational wave will cause the bar to deform, but then the internal stresses inside the bar will push back to return the bar to its natural equilibrium state, leading to oscillations within the bar. A cool extension of this basic idea is that normal modes of the Earth can be excited by gravitational waves. Anyway, given this concept, you can easily see how we could generate radiation -- attach a charge to the end of a Weber bar, for example, and the oscillations of the bar will lead to oscillations of the charge, and therefore generate electromagnetic radiation. In fact that's not so far off of how actual resonant bar detectors were designed -- in that case, a piezoelectric crystal would respond to the mechanical oscillations and produce an electrical current, and while the actual detectors would amplify that current into a measurable signal, you could certainly use that current in a resonant circuit to produce electromagnetic radiation if you wanted to.
(In fact, a somewhat silly answer along these lines is that there is experimental evidence that gravitational waves can cause matter to radiate, since LIGO detected gravitational waves and this information was broadcast to the rest of the world using electromagnetic signals!)
However, gravitational waves have not been detected from resonant bar detectors because astrophysical signals have not been large enough to excite the bars that have been built, and without amplification the electrical signal would be very weak. Laser interferometers give you much better broadband and relatively low frequency sensitivity.
One place in Nature you might find a significant amount of free charge that could radiate, that has some internal structure so would not be purely freely falling, so could plausibly respond to a gravitational wave by emitting electromagnetic radiation, would be some kind of plasma. You can study this problem theoretically, and a gravitational wave can cause the plasma to radiate in both gravitational and electromagnetic waves (see, eg, 1, 2). However, this effect is very small in practice, since gravitational waves are so weak (except very close to the source that generates them).
